# For loop in every 4 instance but also keep track of total count value

Tags: c#, for-loop

The code below generates one 'sign box' when there is 'post box' , then increment the 'sign box' with every 4 'post boxes'.

My problem is I need to calculate 'sign weight' based on 'post box' count and reset on every 4 'post box'. But since the loop is going through the increment once. I can't keep hold of the total number of 'post boxes'.

**NOTE:** The code below is a simple demonstration of the actual code.

```
double qPostBox = 3.0; // for example I have 3 post boxes
int signCount = 0;
int postCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < qPostBox; i++)
{
    postCount++;
    if (i % 4 == 0)
    {
        signCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("SIGN BOX# " + signCount + " SIGN WEIGHT: " + postCount * 4);
        postCount = 1;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("POST BOX# " + postCount);
}
```

The output is:

```
SIGN BOX# 1 SIGN WEIGHT: 4
POST BOX# 1
POST BOX# 2
POST BOX# 3
```

Desired output:

```
SIGN BOX# 1 SIGN WEIGHT: 12
POST BOX# 1
POST BOX# 2
POST BOX# 3
```

Comment: *"I can't keep hold of the total number of 'post boxes'"* -- sure you can. Add another variable.

Comment: The number of post boxes you have must be an integer. Post box number = (i % number_of_boxes) + 1; Post box count = (i / number_of_boxes) + 1;

Comment: @EdPlunkett What if there are 3 post boxes the if would throw in sign weight 4 and thats it. I want the if to know what are the number of boxes when its in the if. if yo know what i mean

Comment: @EvikGhazarian I do not know what you mean. I think you need to explain your requirements more clearly.

Comment: It is unclear how the 'sign weight' relates to the 'post box' count

Comment: @EvikGhazarian So you want one sign weight of 16 for each four signs, and then one for the remainder that's (remainder * 4).

Comment: You're showing the total before you've counted all the weights.  Show the sign weight *after* you've counted the boxes.

Comment: @Dean2690 Each post box weighs 4 units.  The sign box contains a quantity of post boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the order you are doing things.

Count the boxes and *then* show the total weight...

```
int postBoxCount = 5;
int signCount = 0;
int postCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < postBoxCount; i++)
{
    // don't show the total at the very beginning (when i == 0)
    if (i != 0 && i % 4 == 0)
    {
        signCount++;
        Console.WriteLine("SIGN BOX# " + signCount + " SIGN WEIGHT: " + postCount * 4);
        postCount = 0;
    }
    postCount++;
    Console.WriteLine("POST BOX# " + postCount);
}

// show the final total
signCount++;
Console.WriteLine("SIGN BOX# " + signCount + " SIGN WEIGHT: " + postCount * 4);
```

[Here's a working example...](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kIn4x2)

Comment: One question. This doesn't work on post boxes below 4 or the remaining boxes between every 4. for example if its 6 it should be 2 sign box. one weight 16 and the other weight 8. Is  that something possible?

Comment: I've actually updated it since I first posted, because I spotted that exact thing.  The logic at the end `if (i == 1)` was just nonsense.  The loop always ends with showing a POST BOX count, so I changed it so it always shows a total when the loop finishes.  I've updated the dotnetfiddle example as well.  Have a play with that and make sure it's as expected.

Comment: Thanks again :) This can't get any better.